# Oracle Select Query on to many, Inner Query, Getting Not a Group Expression. Duplicates from JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle

Thanks, I have been getting great help from generous people in this forum. I am a beginner in Oracle SQL.

I have a one to many relationship between two VIEWs, which are PERSON_VIEW and PHONE_VIEW. With help, I got a query with case/when for the phone to work, but when I added it back to my main query, it affected my other join with the TASK_VIEW.

I figured I needed to add it as an Inner Query so I get back one result. I added the following to my query. I ran the query in TOAD and it gave me an error, "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression" and highlighted all the PERSON_IDs in the query. If I take the following left join, it runs fine and does not output the phone numbers. Any help is appreciated.

I also noticed that since I am bring back 3 phone numbers (cell, home, and business), it causes dups in my return from TASK. With the Task Inner Join, 
I get results like

Before:
1 John M. Doe   ToDo1:ToDO1, ToDo2:ToDo2

After:
1 John M. Doe   ToDo1:ToDO1,ToDo1:ToDO1,ToDo1:ToDO1, ToDo2:ToDo2,ToDo2:ToDo2,ToDo2:ToDo2

I took the max out of the 3 case statements and it ran the query. But it return a separate row for each phone number like so

1 John Doe   999-999-9999 
1 John Doe   888-888-8888
1 John Doe   222-222-2222

How can I fix this?

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT PERSON_ID, PHONE_TP_SHORT_DESC,
                  max(case when PHONE_TYPE = 'HOME' then PHONE_NUMBER end) as HOME_PHONE,
                  max(case when PHONE_TYPE = 'BUSINESS' then PHONE_NUMBER end) as BUSINESS_PHONE,      
                  max(case when PHONE_TYPE = 'CELL' then PHONE_NUMBER end) as CELL_PHONE 
           FROM PHONE_VIEW) PHONE
ON PERSON.PERSON_ID = PHONE.PERSON_ID AND PHONE.PHONE_TYPE IN ('HOME','BUSINESS','CELL')
```

Here is my entire query which I am trying to debug

```
SELECT PERSON.PERSON_ID, 
       PERSON.FIRST_NAME,
       PERSON.MIDDLE_NAME,
       PERSON.LAST_NAME,
       PERSON.USER_NAME,
       PHONE.HOME_PHONE,
       PHONE.BUSINESS_PHONE,
       PHONE.CELL_PHONE,

LISTAGG(case  
        when SKILLS.SKILL_SHORT_DESC = 'ToDo1' then 'ToDo1:ToDo1'
        when SKILLS.SKILL_SHORT_DESC = 'ToDo2' then 'ToDo2:ToDo2'
        when SKILLS.SKILL_SHORT_DESC = 'ToDo3' then 'ToDo3:ToDo3'
        when SKILLS.SKILL_SHORT_DESC = 'ToDo4' then 'ToDo4:ToDo4'
        when SKILLS.SKILL_SHORT_DESC = 'ToDo5' then 'ToDo5:ToDo5'
        when SKILLS.SKILL_SHORT_DESC = 'ToDo6' then 'ToDo6:ToDo6'
      else ''

 end, ',')  
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TASK.TASK_DESC )  AS TASK

FROM PERSON_VIEW PERSON

LEFT JOIN (SELECT PERSON_ID, PHONE_TP_SHORT_DESC,
                  max(case when PHONE_TYPE = 'HOME' then PHONE_NUMBER end) as HOME_PHONE,
                  max(case when PHONE_TYPE = 'BUSINESS' then PHONE_NUMBER end) as BUSINESS_PHONE,      
                  max(case when PHONE_TYPE = 'CELL' then PHONE_NUMBER end) as CELL_PHONE 
           FROM PHONE_VIEW) PHONE
ON PERSON.PERSON_ID = PHONE.PERSON_ID AND PHONE.PHONE_TYPE IN ('HOME','BUSINESS','CELL')                  


LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT PERSON_ID, TASK_DESC FROM TASK_VIEW) SKILLS
ON SKILLS.PERSON_ID = PERSON.PERSON_ID


GROUP BY 
PERSON.PERSON_ID,
PERSON.FIRST_NAME,
PERSON.MIDDLE_NAME, 
PERSON.LAST_NAME,
PERSON.USER_NAME,
PHONE.HOME_PHONE,
PHONE.BUSINESS_PHONE,
PHONE.CELL_PHONE
```

Answer (score 0):

I do see one problem with your query.  You have a `LEFT JOIN` to the following subquery:

```
(SELECT PERSON_ID,
        PHONE_TP_SHORT_DESC,
        max(case when PHONE_TYPE = 'HOME' then PHONE_NUMBER end) as HOME_PHONE,
        max(case when PHONE_TYPE = 'BUSINESS' then PHONE_NUMBER end) as BUSINESS_PHONE,      
        max(case when PHONE_TYPE = 'CELL' then PHONE_NUMBER end) as CELL_PHONE 
 FROM PHONE_VIEW) PHONE
```

However, in the `ON` condition you refer to a column called `PHONE_TYPE`:

```
ON PERSON.PERSON_ID = PHONE.PERSON_ID AND
   PHONE.PHONE_TYPE IN ('HOME','BUSINESS','CELL')
```

There is no column called `PHONE_TYPE` available, and so I would expect an error from this.  Sometimes the error message you get from a database (or compiler) can be misleading in that it doesn't always reveal the root cause of the problem.

Another possible cause for error is that you are using views, and they behave differently from tables.

Comment: Any rational behind thinking that  PHONE_TYPE is not available in the table PHONE_VIEW or its just your guess or you want to say one cannot use a column in where clause if its not in select list.

Comment: The alias `PHONE` refers to a sub query AFAIK.  Only columns selected in that subquery should be available outside the subquery.

Comment: Ohhh..i didnt see he used PHONE.PHONE_TYPE....I asked coz i thought he used PHONE_VIEW.PHONE_TYPE..My mistake

Comment: @Raj_Te Yes it is confusing...this is probably how the mistake was made in the first place.